# Ionic or Cordova plugin for sending bluetooth broadcast messages from the phone

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there a plugin for Ionic or Cordova that can be used to send Bluetooth/BLE broadcast from Android and iOS devices?

I know I can write the plugin myself, but I am wondering if there is something already available.